# Tumblr API returning error code 1016

Tags: api, tumblr, error-code

I have an Google Chrome extension that is using Tumblr API for making new posts in my blog.
And it was working fine until lately. At some point Tumblr API stopped accepting my requests.
This is what I am getting when requesting Tumblr API https://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/chestozo.tumblr.com/post:

```
{
  "meta": {
    "status": 401,
    "msg": "Unauthorized"
  },
  "response": [],
  "errors": [
    {
      "title": "Unauthorized",
      "code": 1016,
      "detail": "Unable to authorize"
    }
  ]
}
```

After searching the web for Tumblr API error codes I could not find anything about this error code.
Any idea what does it mean?

Answer (score 1):

After some more investigation it turns out that this is due to `Authorization` header format that was used in my extension which was like this:

```
Authorization: OAuth oauth_nonce="gTle8" oauth_timestamp="1526133184" 
oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1" oauth_consumer_key="vGKikr...lQt4Ozi"
oauth_token="NPIRR5h...p0wQz" oauth_signature="kEf7C...2No99Q%3D"
```

There were no commas after different OAuth parameters. And it was working for some years :) until at some point probably Tumblr stopped supporting this old format.

All I had to do was to add commas after each parameters and all is good now:

```
Authorization: OAuth oauth_nonce="FBioO", oauth_timestamp="1526133278",
oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_consumer_key="vGKikr2u...t4Ozi",
oauth_token="eRPGCCe...DWaw4cr", oauth_signature="m0FmC...hU%3D"
```